# Replace not numbers or words to underscore but leave dash and remove spaces around it

Tags: javascript, regex

So I got this string

```
'word word - word word 24/03/21'
```

And I would like to convert it to

```
'word_word-word_word_24_03_21'
```

I have tried this

```
replace(/[^aA-zZ0-9]/g, '_')
```

But I get this instead

```
word_word___word_word_24_03_21
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use 2 `.replace()` calls:

```js
const s = 'word word - word word 24/03/21'
var r = s.replace(/\s*-\s*/g, '-').replace(/[^-\w]+/g, '_')

console.log(r)
//=> "word_word-word_word_24_03_21"
```

**Explanation:**

- `.replace(/\s*-\s*/g, '-')`: Remove surrounding spaces of a hyphen
- `.replace(/[^-\w]+/g, '_')`: Replace all character that are not a hyphen and not a word character with an underscore

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```js
console.log(
  'word word - word word 24/03/21'.replace(/\s*(-)\s*|[^\w-]+/g, (x,y) => y || "_")
)
```

Here,

- `/\s*(-)\s*|[^\w-]+/g` - matches and captures into Group 1 a `-` enclosed with zero or more whitespaces, and just matches any non-word char excluding `-`
- `(x,y) => y || "_")` - replaces with Group 1 if it was matched, and if not, replacement is a `_` char.

Answer (score 1):

With a function for [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) and an alternation in the pattern, you could also match:

- `(\s*-\s*)` Match a `-` between optional whtiespace chars
- `|` Or
- `[^a-zA-Z0-9-]+` Match 1+ times any of the listed ranges

In the callback, check if group 1 exists. If it does, return only a `-`, else return `_`

**Note** that this notation `[^aA-zZ0-9]` is not the same as `[a-zA-Z0-9]`, see what `[A-z]` [matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771901/why-is-this-regex-allowing-a-caret).

```js
let s = "word word - word word 24/03/21";
s = s.replace(/(\s*-\s*)|[^a-zA-Z0-9-]+/g, (_, g1) => g1 ? "-" : "_");
console.log(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `+` regex operator to replace 1 or more continuous matches at once.

```js
let s = 'word word - word word 24/03/21';
let r = s
  .replace(/[^aA-zZ0-9]*-[^aA-zZ0-9]*/g, '-')
  .replace(/[^aA-zZ0-9-]+/g, '_');

console.log(r);
// 'word_word-word_word_24_03_21'
```

Comment: OP wants to preserve hyphens. This removes them

Comment: @CarlMarkham Thanks for pointing that out. Updated.

Comment: Running the snippet still returns `word_word_word_word_24_03_21`

Comment: @CarlMarkham updated again., forgot to to exclude `-` in th 2nd regex